# Spring validation with Javax.validation redirects to 400

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, jsr

I am working on a Spring-MVC application, and I want to validate some data. Currently I am able to validate the data with no problems. Only thing is if the data is invalid, I would like to go to another JSP page, which is not happening right now. Instead I get an Apache 400 error, request was sent syntactically incorrect. Can anyone tell me what all is remaining to implement in validation.

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPersons(Model model) {
        Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        if(!(person==null)){
            return "redirect:/canvas/list";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
         //   model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
            model.addAttribute("notices",new Notes());
            model.addAttribute("canvases",new Canvas());
            return "person";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@Valid Person person,@ModelAttribute("person") Person p,Model model,BindingResult bindingResult){

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "redirect:/";
        }
            this.personService.addPerson(p);
            return "redirect:/";

    }
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

    @NotEmpty @Email
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter password")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Size(min = 2,max = 30)
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Size(min = 2,max = 50)
    @Column(name = "secretquestion")
    private String secretquestion;


    @Size(min = 2,max = 500)
    @Column(name = "secretanswer")
    private String secretanswer;
}
```

JSP :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="firstName">
            <spring:message text="FirstName"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="firstName" />
    </td>
    <td><form:errors path="firstName"/>Please enter Firstname properly</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="username">
            <spring:message text="Email"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="username" />
    </td>
    <td><form:errors path="username"/>Please enter Email properly</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="password">
            <spring:message text="Password"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="password" />
    </td>
    <td><form:errors path="password"/>Please enter password properly</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    <form:label path="secretquestion">
        <spring:message text="secretquestion"/>
    </form:label>
</td>
<td>
    <form:input path="secretquestion" />
</td>
    <td><form:errors path="secretquestion"/>Please enter secretquestion properly</td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="secretanswer">
            <spring:message text="secretanswer"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="secretanswer" />
    </td>
    <td><form:errors path="secretanswer"/>Please enter secretanswer properly</td>
</tr>
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
 <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"/>
```

Pom.xml

```
<!-- Validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any pointers would be nice. Mainly I would like to avoid going on Apache 400, but just display what exactly went wrong with the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is might be because of `public String addPerson(@Valid Person person,@ModelAttribute("person") Person p,Model model,BindingResult bindingResult)` signature . 
`BindingResult` must follow `@ModelAttribute` as method signature might have more that one model object and Spring will create a separate BindingResult instance for each of them.That is why when the data is invalid spring is not able to bind errors to `BindingResult` and throws 400 error.

Try changing method signature to `public String addPerson(@Valid Person person,@ModelAttribute("person") Person p,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model)`.

Read more on [BindingResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: Thank you. That nailed the problem. I am just looking how to add custom messages when a specific field goes wrong, any ideas?